# How set environment variable on capistrano deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

In my rails app, i set response header from env:

```ruby
response.headers['application-version'] = ENV["APPLICATION_VERSION"]
```

I try set env variable in capistrano deploy file, but this don't work.

```ruby
set :default_environment, {
    'APPLICATION_VERSION' => Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%L')
}
```

How i set env variable on deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm install gem Figaro, update capistrano2 file:

```js
task :set_version do
  put 'application_version: ' + Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%L'), "#{current_path}/config/application.yml"
end

before 'deploy:start', 'set_version'
```

And where I need application_version variable, I get it in rails file:

```js
app_version = Figaro.env.application_version
```

p.s: 'deploy:restart' don't reload config/application.yml file, need: 'deploy:stop' and 'deploy:start'

Answer (score 4):

Setting `default_environment` (or `default_env` for Capistrano 3.x) will only set the variables **during deploy commands**. From the [docs](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Significant-Configuration-Variables):

> A hash that can be used to set environment variables that should be present for all commands that are executed.

If you want to set environment variables to be used by your rails server---which is another process, another vm instance, in another login session---you need to set the env variables for the session its being executed, e.g. via `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.zshrc` or whatever shell you're using. You can also use some environment variable manager like [direnv](https://github.com/zimbatm/direnv/), [rbenv-vars](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-vars), etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Now I'm trying use gem figaro for emulate env variable ( http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html )

Answer (score 0):

In one Rails app, I use Capistrano 3. I set my variables with `default_env`

```
set :default_env, {
  'APPLICATION_VERSION' => Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%L')
}
```

<strike>For another Rails app, I use Capistrano 2. There I use `:default_environment` to set variables.</strike>

Comment: I use Capistrano 2 and rails 3, but :default_environment not setting env variable.

Comment: @Kroid Really? Ups. I have to check my deploy script. Thx. I do not know where my variables are coming from ;-)

Comment: `default_env` only sets the variable during the deploy.